# ¿Cómo invoco un método de una clase a otra?

Tags: java, android

Tengo en mi aplicación varios activity, la principal es la del login y el home. Lo que necesito es que alguna de las funciones del home puedan ser accesadas sin iniciar sesión, entonces puse un botón en el login que debería hacer lo mismo que el botón del home, pero al invocar el método esta se cierra. ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

LoginActivity: aquí es donde tengo que invocar la función vinculada al btnSucursales. Cuando realizo el onclicklistener y lo clickeo en el simulador, este crashea

```
package main.laboratus.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo;
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManager;
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManagerFactory;
import com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallState;
import com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallStateUpdatedListener;
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.AppUpdateType;
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.InstallStatus;
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.UpdateAvailability;
import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;
import main.laboratus.app.main.HomeFragment;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Button btnLogin;
     ImageView btnSucursales, btnPromociones;
     EditText edUsername, edPassword;
     TextView tvForgetPassword;
    HomeFragment metodo = new HomeFragment();
    AppUpdateManager mAppUpdateManager;
    private final static int RC_APP_UPDATE=659;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnSucursales = findViewById(R.id.btnSucursales);
        btnPromociones = findViewById(R.id.btnPromociones);
        edUsername = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        edPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        tvForgetPassword = findViewById(R.id.tvForgetPassword);

        tvForgetPassword.setOnClickListener(view -> startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UsernameActivity.class)));
        
//
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString()) ) {
                String message = "Todas las entradas requeridas ..";
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Autenticando usuario...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loginUser(1,edUsername.getText().toString(),edPassword.getText().toString());
            }

        });





        mAppUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        mAppUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo result)
            {
                if(result.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                        && result.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mAppUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(result,AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE, LoginActivity.this
                                ,RC_APP_UPDATE);

                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        mAppUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
    /* we can check without requestCode == RC_APP_UPDATE because
    we known exactly there is only requestCode from  startUpdateFlowForResult() */
        if(requestCode == RC_APP_UPDATE && resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener =new InstallStateUpdatedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStateUpdate(InstallState state)
        {
            if(state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED)
            {
                showCompletedUpdate();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        if(mAppUpdateManager!=null) mAppUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
        super.onStop();

    }


    public void loginUser(Integer ptipoUsuario, String pUsuario, String pClave){
        Call<String> loginResponseCall = ApiClient.getService().loginUser(ptipoUsuario, pUsuario,pClave);
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body() , LoginResponse.class);

                    if (loginResponse.getNom_paciente().equals("0")) {
                        Toasty.error(LoginActivity.this, "No se encontró tal usuario.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                    }else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("data", loginResponse)
                                .putExtra("pId",Integer.parseInt(pUsuario)));
                        finish();
                    }


                }else{
                    String message = "Ocurrió un error por favor intente más tarde...";
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                String message = t.getLocalizedMessage();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void showCompletedUpdate()
    {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"New app is ready!",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Install", new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mAppUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error que se muestra? Importante agregar esta información, revisa [ask] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es que crees un método que realice el proceso:

```
public void myMetodo(Context context){

           if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString()) ) {
                String message = "Todas las entradas requeridas ..";
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Context, "Autenticando usuario...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loginUser(1, edUsername.getText().toString(), edPassword.getText().toString());
            }

}
```

y este sea llamado por tus botones:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {

   myMetodo(LoginActivity.this);

});
```

Pero en este caso solo funcionaría si las referencias de las vistas se encuentran dentro del layout .xml que carga la `Activity` desde donde llamas el método. Por ejemplo si haces referencia a los `EditText` "edUsername" y "edPassword" y estos no se encuentran en el layout de la `Activity` obtendrías un error `NullPointerException` :

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edUsername.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(edPassword.getText().toString()) ) {
    ... 
    ...
```